# How to stop an infinite travel between portal A and B?

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, logic

I'am Working on a 2D game with unity , and I am trying to add a portal system like blackholes, when the player enter Blackhole A he get teleported to blackhole B and vice versa ...

**The main issue is** that when the player object position get changed to blackhole "B", since blackhole B is a portal itself, the player get stucked in a infinite travel between A and B leading to many bug and a very bad behaviour .

**What I want** is to  be able to move from portal A to B and move back from portal B to A . *Without getting stuck in a infinit travel between A & B*

Here the code responsable for that :

```
public GameObject exitBL ;
    public bool teleport = false;
    public Collider2D coll;
            // Use this for initialization
            void Start ()
            {

    }

            // Update is called once per frame
            void Update ()
    {
            if (teleport) {
                    exitBL.GetComponent<BlackHolePortal>().enabled = false; // Disable the logic for portal B which is exitBl
                    goToBl(coll);
                            }

    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){
            if (col.tag == "Player") {
                    coll = col;
                    //col.transform.position = new Vector3 (exitBL.transform.position.x  , exitBL.transform.position.y , 0f);
                    teleport = true;


                            }

    }
    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col){
            if (col.tag == "Player") {
                    exitBL.GetComponent<BlackHolePortal>().enabled = true;
                            }

            }
    void goToBl(Collider2D col){
            teleport = false;
             col.transform.position = new Vector3 (exitBL.transform.position.x + 1.0f  , exitBL.transform.position.y + 1.0f  , 0f);

            coll.rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (-1f,2f));


    }
```

Even If I'am adding `AddForce()` to move from the Portal B quickly, the line which take care of moving the player pos to the portal pos run in an infinite way since the player will move to a portal B which is a portal too, so the player get back to portal A..etc .

Is there any way to stop this behaviour ? I need some help in the logic .

**Edit** : I've changed the code : Now I'am disabling the logic when it get to teleported . But i get the same issue.

**Note ** : Right now, I am making my collider very small and teleporting my player and adding an offset, this solution work, but there should be a better way .

---

Here some stuff I've done and which doesn't work or work partially :

1. Using a bool var called teleport, this one get a true value when it enter the trigger collider, and check for that var in Update, if true do `goToBl()` (Update run once per frame ) ( doesn't work)

   2. Using the same bool and check if it's true in the Update (), then disable the script for portal B; until the pleyr get out of it. (doesn't work) .
   3. Making black hole portal colliders very small and then move to the portal position + 1; This solution is not a final one (just a workaround), it works partially, sometimes it works very good, sometimes it doesn't work .

Can any one suggest me a solution to solve this problem ?

Thank's !

Comment: So character position alone is what allows them into a portal? I would suppress the portal logic if the character has come through it, then when they leave the bounding area of the portal you can reset the suppression of the logic until they move back into it again. This sounds like what you have already tried though.

Comment: This is called *chatter* and typical solution is to implement hysteresis: after teleporting you can't teleport back unless moves away a bit.

Comment: Science Note: "Blackholes" are *not* a portal system.  Theorized *wormholes* may be.

Comment: @DeltaWeb that code is small enough, don't make us click a link to get it, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30398389/edit) and put the code in there. (It is generally considered "bad manners" on this site to make a user go to a external source to get to code)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to have the player position `>+1` (in the x or y axis) of the portal so that they are actually teleported in front of the portal...

But, if for whatever reason you want them to teleport directly to the portal: after each teleport don't allow then player to teleport again until they have walked away from the teleportor position.

This can be done using `events` and a simple `bool` named `canTeleport`.

Comment: +1.  For @DeltaWeb  I would suggest an enhancement to this solution: rather than teleporting them when thet *enter* the portal, instead, teleport them when they are already *in* the portal, and are *moving out of the portal*, then teleport them to the other portal, adding in their movement offset so that they will appear outside of the target portal and with a velocity away from it.

Comment: Love that addition to the solution. @RBarryYoung. Delta, I am looking into the code you sent me.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing about the technical aspect, what you want in fact is to be out of reach of the portal B when you teleport A => B.

A easy solution would be to place your character little bit further hence he has to step back to enter again in the portal.

Comment: I said in the question (look number 3 in the end) that I've tried that, but I think that it's not the best solution out there, I am look for a technical to makethis line of code only run once .

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 possible solutions for you:

1. (my opinion is the best)-

Use a time counter each portal. --> when your char is in position of a portal start counting like 3 seconds and then the teleport will active. (then if the player won't leave the other teleport in 3 seconds he will get teleported back)

2. Use "proximity" --> use a boolean varible which is false always, just if the char reach "1 space" from the teleport it is true, then only teleport if that bool is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Portal
{
    public bool canBeTeleportedTo = true;
    public Portal partnerPortal; // Assign this however you want

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "Player")
        {
            if (partnerPortal.canBeTeleportedTo == true)
            {
                TeleportToPartner(col);
            }
        }

    }
    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col){
        if (col.tag == "Player")
        {
            partnerPortal.canBeTeleportedTo = true;
        }

    }

    void TeleportToPartner(Collider2D col)
    {
        canBeTeleportedTo = false;

        col.transform.position = new Vector3 (partnerPortal.transform.position.x , partnerPortal.transform.position.y, 0f);

        col.rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (-1f,2f));
    }
}
```

You need a link between your portals to poll whether or not you should initiate a teleport as your OnTriggerEnters will always be called. Something like the above should work as you poll your destination to see whether or not you are allowed to teleport the player. This way your player must exit a portal completely before the portal will teleport them again.