# Logic: Prevent infinite loop when using portals

Tags: javascript, logic

In a game that I am currently working on, there are portals, which are linked in pairs of two. Whenever the player enters a portal, it should be teleported to the other portal that is linked to the portal that they just entered. The problem is, that once it is teleported over, the other portal see's that the player is collding with it, and will teleport it back to the first, which will send it back and so on. The code for this porject is large and over many files, but here is the most important:

(Javascript, ignore the frame and pause vaibles, those are for animation)

```
export class Portal extends gameObject{
    constructor(x, y, size, id){
        super(x, y, size);
        this.currentFrame = 0;//updated when (below) > (2 below)
        this.countingFrame =0;//update every time;
        this.pause = 3;//frames between frames
        this.id = id;
        this.justVisited = false;
    }
    update(player, portals){
        if(this.countingFrame >= this.pause){
            this.currentFrame = (this.currentFrame + 1) % 4;
            this.countingFrame = 0;
        }else{
            this.countingFrame ++;
        }
        if(super.checkPlayerCollision(player)){
            this.justVisited = true;
            for(let i in portals){
                if(this.id === portals[i].id && portals[i] !== this && !portals[i].justVisited){
                    player.x = portals[i].x;
                    player.y = portals[i].y;
                }
            }
        }else{
            for(let i in portals){
                if(this.id === portals[i].id && portals[i] !== this && portals[i].justVisited){
                    this.justVisited = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    render(canvas, spritesheet){
        super.render(canvas, spritesheet, this.currentFrame , 26);
    }
}
```

This is one attempt at patching it up, but it still failed. How can I make it so that the player goes throught the first one as soon as it collides, comes out the second, and won't retrun to the first untill the player moves off and then back on?

EDIT:After a little bit of seaching, the answer that was most often given to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398389/how-to-stop-an-infinite-travel-between-portal-a-and-b?rq=1) question was "*Move the player outside the reach of the second portal when it teleports over there*". This will not work in my case, because when the player updates, his position changes with respect to the amount of time seince the last frame. In a perfet world, that would be ok, but because it is not perfect, the player cannot reliably be on a single point. Also, it would look weird if I moved it out of the hitbox entirely, so that doesn't work either.

Comment: Make it so that the player cannot interact with the portal until he moves out of it and back in again.

Comment: @FireCubes, Yes, that would work, the probelm is figuring out when the player has moved out. Say that I had a varible called movedOut. And if the block dectects collsion with the player, movedOut is set to false. When it doesn't detect the player, it is set to true. If I teleport the player over, collision is not dected, and movedOut would be true, meaning that I could teleport back, and the loop continues

Comment: what? I don't understand

Comment: @FireCubez Ok, first: the idea that having the portal be inactive untill the player steps off and steps back on again is rock solid, and will work. The problem is determining when the player steps off. Assume that we have two portals, pA and pB, and that they all follow the same logic. If the player collides with pA, then it is sent to pB. And vice versa

Comment: If they both have a bool called 'steppedOff', which does what it says, then we could say something like 'if(this.steppedOff && other.steppedOff){teleport}'

Comment: The problem is finiding out where that steppedOff is turned on or off. If I say to set it to false when the player steps on any portal, and set it to true the moment it does not detect collision, then teleporting counts as moving it off and you are back at the begining